# get two elements from array inside an object

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, xml

I have this JSON

```json
   let data =  {
     "details":[
      {
       "title": "title1", 
       "tags":[
        "no-search",
        "option1",
        "text1"
       ]
      },
      {
       "title": "title2", 
       "tags":[
        "no-search",
        "option1",
        "text2"
       ]
      },
     ]
    }
```

and I want to get title 2, but I need to search in "tags" the last 2 elements ("option1", "testing-text2"), i trying to use the "find function", but it just gets 1 element, how can I get those two elements to get title 2?

I tried with

```js
    var myData = data.find(item => item.tags === 'option1' && item.tags === 'text2');
```

but it returns undefined, I need to get the last 2 items, because option1 could change, and I need to get just the title, tags are just for filter it

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is/was incorrect. Try using `Array.prototype.map` to get the titles.

```js
let data = {
  "details": [
    {
      "title": "title1",
      "tags": [
        "no-search",
        "option1",
        "text1"
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "title2",
      "tags": [
        "no-search",
        "option1",
        "text2"
      ]
    }
  ]
};
console.log(data.details.map(i=>i.title));
```